# Как выбрать фотографию из галереи с помощью Picasso?

Tags: android

Мне кажется в Load я должен поставить ссылку на фотографию. Но каким образом мне получить эту ссылку?

Comment: какая фотография не имеет отношения? вы о той что в вопросе была?

Comment: да именно про эту. Где опускающийся список был

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1):

Выбор происходит при помощи `OnActivityResult`. Будем рассматривать на примере `imageView`:

```
imageView  = findViewById(R.id.image_display);
```

Вызов диалога для выбора фото:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
```

Обработка полученного результата и сеттинг в виджет:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {

                Uri selectedImageURI = data.getData();
                Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(selectedImageURI).noPlaceholder().centerCrop().fit()
                        .into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_display));
            }

        }
    }
```

Вот есть [туториал/первоисточник](https://medium.com/@nickkorage95/selecting-images-from-the-gallery-c9c7baa936d1) по данному вопросу

Comment: Спасибо!!! Ты мне очень помог!

Comment: А как это полученное изображение сделать круглым? Как на аве

Comment: Сделайте drawable нужной вам формы и сетьте в нужном вам виджете

Comment: Не работает. Я сделал drawable форму и поставил на ImageView. Но она не работает

Comment: Что значит не работает? Как вы его сетите?

Comment: Благодарю,чел))